# Which code is more efficient, extra If statement or repeated function

Tags: c, performance, if-statement, pic

With regards to coding in C, which would be faster, to check the statement with an If, or I just run the function anyway for example say the output is already 1.

```
if(a==b && output!=1)
{
    output=1;
}
```

Or

```
if(a==b)
{
    output=1;
}
```

In the first code, an extra check has to be run every time the code runs.

In the second you are running the code repeatedly unnecessarily

Which is more efficient??

Comment: _In the first code, an extra check has to be run every time the code runs_ Because of short-circuiting, the 2nd condition will not be checked if `a != b`.

Comment: Have you considered using `output = (a == b)`?

Comment: You could just say: `output = (a==b);`

Comment: If you're wondering which is faster, have you tried either profiling it or looking at the generated assembly?

Comment: Don't care.  Let the compiler figure it out for you.  Something this tiny is expensive in time and money to worry about for more than a minute or two.  If you really care, look at the asm output on an optimized build and compare.

Comment: What type is `output`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton `output = (a == b)` is not the same functionality as either of OP's code samples.  With OP's code `ouput` is not changed when `a != b`.

Comment: I understand the gain would be negligible in this example, I was asking more to better understand the assemblers outputs, but thanks for your replies, in regards to the output = (a==b) answers that would only work if output was logical, a mistake in my example, which was theoretical not practical

Comment: Efficiency can be measured in performance, code space, coder's time, maintenance, etc.  `if(a==b && output!=1)` does not win code space, coder's time, maintenance.  Perfromance winner depends on many factors

Comment: Poor SO etiquette to significantly change the question after answers arrive.  Post rolled-back.

Comment: Sorry changed it to clarify, for those curious I changed output = 1 to output = c, c being some variable

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The OP's reply to my comment, if there had been one, might have revealed sufficient information to eliminate the `if` or show that really is necessary. It's being run on a PIC, so eliminating an `if` might give better performance, or maybe it's a `volatile` with other implications. I could be completely wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMorton   Agree about embedded concerns.  I myself have coded like `if(a==b && output!=1)` simply for concerns about writing a HW reg. - never though for performance as easier to improve in other code areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question basically boils down to the question of is a compare less expensive than a variable assignment.  For integers, the answer is no.  I am assuming this will be in a tight loop where the variables will already be in the CPU level 1 cache.  The compare will compile down to Op codes like:

```
1) Move "output" memory locations data into Register A
2) Put  1 into Register B
3) Jump <somewhere> if Register A == Register B.
```

You might get an optimization where 2) is not done if comparing to 0 because there are special op codes for comparing to 0 in most CPUs.

The assignment will compiler to op codes like:

```
1) Put 1 into Register A
2) Push Register A to memory location of output
```

The question come down to clock cycles spent for each of the op codes.  I think that they are all likely to be exactly the same clock cycles.

Comment: In case of int, is generally faster to assing than to compare. But the compare is still faster if you are comparing to zero (with any data time, I assume) thanks to the special op code. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: @YusefMaali processors that have a special 0 compare can readily have a special 0 assign.

Comment: @Yusef Maali   If you are comparing to 0, then the compare and the assign operations are the same.  The compare to zero has 2 steps:  Step 1, move data to register.  Step 2, Jump if register is 0.  The assignment is also 2 steps.

Comment: @Yusef Maali,  The "special" 0 compare is kind of different from a special "0" assign.  The Zero compare is a bunch of "OP-codes".  There is usually one for each register on the CPU.  The codes are written in assembler as "JZ<register>" i.e. Jump if zero and "JNZ<register>" Jump if not zero.  My step 3) above may technically be 2 steps.  XOR A,B which compares registers A and B and sets the non-matching bits in "C" and JZC.  Some CPUs may have an op-code that does both in 1 step.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless any possible optimization, as shown in the comments, the first code is less efficient than the second code due to the extra check.

Beware of your data meaning, that check may be mandatory.
If not, you should optimize your code as suggested.

---

Edit

I'm assuming your question to be more theoretical than practical. In any real scenario, the data context assume a huge role when we want to optimize some code.
The code don't need to be fast itself, but need to be fast in processing its data.

Comment: That is not necessary true, there are additional factors in play, such as the probability of the second condition being true and the number of times it executes. See other answers, for example

Comment: I think the question is more theoretical than practical. He is not caring about the meaning of the data (which in optimization is the key), so no data distribution comes into play. He is just comparing two possibile code flows, the second one has an extra check. Maybe we should talk if is more more expensive a more frequent assignement (`output=1`) even when not necessary than to check its value to avoid the assignemnt